# Convert json structure to row

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE myrecord AS
id INT
other TEXT
attributes JSONB
```

The attributes are structured like this:

```
[
   {"name": "a", "value": "1"},
   {"name": "b", "value": "2"}
]
```

I'd like to convert that to a result like:

```
id INT, other TEXT, a TEXT, b TEXT
```

So that for a given row like

```
1 | "foo" | {..as above..}
```

I get a result like

```
1 | "foo" | "1" | "2"
```

---

Right now I'm able to unpack the attribute structure like this:

```
CREATE TYPE myrecord_attributes AS (name TEXT, value TEXT);

SELECT
   id,
   other,
   (json_populate_recordset(NULL :: myrecord_attributes,
                            attributes :: JSON)).*
FROM myrecord
```

But with that I get results like:

```
1 | "foo" | "a" | "1"
1 | "foo" | "b" | "2"
```

**How can I flatten the result from `json_populate_recordset` into the appropriate structure? I'm also open to alternate solutions which don't use it like that at all.**

I'm using postgres 9.4 if that matters

Comment: On your result where does `"foo"` came from? based on your given set.

Comment: Also you are missing a `}` on your json input

Comment: @JorgeCampos the `"foo"` is an example value in the `other TEXT` column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as this:

```
select m.id, 
       m.other, 
       x.value::jsonb->>'name' as name, 
       x.value::jsonb->>'value' as value
  from myrecord m, 
       json_array_elements(m.attributes) x;
```

And if you like it to return the values with double quotes just change `->>` to `->`

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/450cc/9

This is making use of the implicit [`LATERAL JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) in Postgres 9.3 or later.

**EDIT**

My first solution did not meet the OP's requirements, so, I've created another solution:

```
select m.id, 
       m.other, 
       max(case when x.value::json->>'name' = 'a' 
                  then x.value::json->>'value' else '' end) as a,
       max(case when x.value::json->>'name' = 'b' 
                  then x.value::json->>'value' else '' end) as b
  from myrecord m, 
       json_array_elements(m.attributes) x
 group by m.id, 
          m.other;
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/450cc/14

Comment: Your fiddle shows the result of that query being what I already have with `json_populate_recordset`. I want to convert from that form into one where there's a one to one mapping between `myrecord` rows and output rows, but with the output having extra columns of `a`, `b`.

Comment: By your comment on @Patrick answer you want that columns be dynamic created, in order to do that you have to, at least, know your json structure so you can pre define your columns. Other than that you will end up with a  function solution. Can you be more clear on your question about how much or which other values could be possible on your json? Now you have just name and value is it possible to other unknown values to appear there? Or what can be different.

Comment: I do know what specific names I want. I'll edit the question to clarify

Comment: Looks like it should work for me; If you edit it into the answer I can accept it.

Comment: @Daenyth Ok! I will do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `jsonb` array always has two elements as given in your question, you can explicitly select all required elements:

```
SELECT id, other, (attributes->0)->>'value' AS a, (attributes->1)->>'value' AS b
FROM myrecord;
```

Comment: No, it has multiple more, and I'm not certain that they will be any specific order. I can't just index, I need to pull out values by name.